# Any user friendly .NET reference guides for C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am mainly a Python programmer. Now I am trying to learn C# .NET.

I see there is a .NET Framework Reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d11h6832.aspx

But it is quite user unfriendly. I can't even find System.Console without digging through System namespace even though they have System.CodeDom or System.Collections.

I personally think the [python library reference](http://docs.python.org/library/) is pretty good. So what I want to know is if there are any alternative references for .NET that are more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MSDN one of the small things that is good about it is that if you're looking for documentation on a specific type then you can just type in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/< TYPE NAME WITH NAMESPACE >.aspx and you should get documentation for that class.

Other than that just hang out on SO and read a few books.

Answer (score 2):

I use a bookmarklet to MSDN, just save this as a bookmark:

```
javascript:var a = prompt('MSDN Reference Lookup', 'Enter class name');if(a!=null){window.location='http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/' + a + '.aspx';}
```

And enter fully qualified class names (like System.IO.StreamReader) and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just getting started, check out the [DZone RefCard](http://refcardz.dzone.com/announcements/coredotnet) for Core .NET. There really isn't any direct C# data, but it will give you a nice overview of the language and may help for some of the simpler issues you're trying to resolve.

Comment: Oh snap! I just got to the end of the RefCard and found out it was written by Jon Skeet! Proof that RefCard are merely various aspects of Jon Skeet's knowledge. 8^D